# Docker container: Ports field empty

Tags: docker

I have dockerfile for a spring boot app as:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-slim AS build

VOLUME /tmp
ADD . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests
RUN curl -L https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-java-instrumentation/releases/download/v1.27.0/aws-opentelemetry-agent.jar --output opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar", "-jar", "target/tempo-exp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]
```

In application.properties, I have set server.port as 8888.

I create image:

```
docker build . -t test-spring-app
```

Image is created without any issue. Now I launch container with -p for port mapping:

```
docker run test-spring-app -p 8888:8888
```

When I check container(docker ps)

[image]

Ports is empty.

Why is this so?

Comment: I guess port option should be given before the image name, i.e ```docker run -p 8888:8888 test-spring-app```

Comment: all parameters after image name is interpreted as a entrypoint [`COMMAND`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run) → `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, use the command:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 test-spring-app
```

The motivation is that `docker run` command has this sintax

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

where:

- `[OPTIONS]` is the list of options to use to run the container. [Here the complete list of options available](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options)
- `[COMMAND] [ARG...]` is the list of commands that will be passed to the container and will run inside it.